# Rulings on listening to songs that has swearing on it

Tags: islamic-basis

Salam brothers and sisters, what is the ruling for people that listen to a song that has swearing, and sang along the lyrics. For example, before this I listen to a song, the lyrics is something like this :

'My death swear is only for you' (to a girl)

What is the ruling on this ?
1.  I know that this is wrong because as I know swearing is only made in the names of Allah.
2. What if I utter the words along with the lyrics, does that mean I am swearing and have to pay kafarah although I have no intention to swear?

Thank you, anyone could answer my question.

Comment: Isn't listening to Music by itself considered as haram by a majority of scholars? What's the use of asking for any type of Music/Song texts a special question. If the ruling applies to the main act than specifying is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to pay Kaffarah for an oath on Allah.

But, what you have done is very sinful:

> He who swears by anyone or anything other than Allah, has indeed committed an act of Kufr or Shirk' ([Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18/201))

You should sincerely repent, and avoid the situation again.